# Convert Google Colab notebook to PDF / HTML?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I would like to know if there is a way in Google Colab that can collate outputs nicely, just like Markdown in R and how IPython Notebook can be converted to pdf and html format?

My output consists of multiple tables, graphs etc. I would like to preferably pretty print them into one file, of which some part are presentable enough to be used in a report.If there's no such method, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Do you mean creating a "text" cell?

Comment: @norok2 Hi I would like to output all my Google Colab results collectively in a nice way.

Comment: Isn't what you use in Google Colab a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @AMC It appears to me Google Colab doesn't have some functions in Jupyter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save / export an IPython notebook (menu: `File` / `Download .ipynb`) and then use Jupyter to save to PDF.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you mean that there's no possible way in Google Colab, and I have to output via IPython Notebook anyway?

Comment: I see no other simple way of doing what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create a pdf in colab itself using nbconvert.

```py
!apt update
!apt install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended

import re, pathlib, shutil

# Get a list of all your Notebooks
notebooks = [x for x in pathlib.Path("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks").iterdir() if 
             re.search(r"\.ipynb", x.name, flags = re.I)]

for i, n in enumerate(notebooks):
    print(f"\nProcessing  [{i+1:{len(str(len(notebooks)))}d}/{len(notebooks)}]  {n.name}\n")

    # Optionally copy your notebooks from gdrive to your vm
    shutil.copy(n, n.name)
    n = pathlib.Path(n.name)

    !jupyter nbconvert "{n.as_posix()}" --to pdf --output "{n.stem.replace(" ", "_")}"
```

Instead of using a magic to run nbconvert you could also use `subprocess`

```py
s = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(
    f'jupyter nbconvert "{n.as_posix()}" --to pdf --output "{n.stem.replace(" ", "_")}"'
    ), shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
s.wait()
s.stdout.read()
```

There are also more packages available regarding xetex in case you use a very sophisticated template.

```sh
sudo apt install pandoc nbconvert texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-generic-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

In Colab, an easy alternative will be to use the browser's print functionality.

1. click on `file` on the toolbar & select print.
2. select `Save as PDF` - this will download the notebook to your PC as pdf.

Comment: The browser functionality usually gives incomplete code