# Error converting Google Colab to PDF using nbconvert without inputs: --no-input command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation, google-colaboratory, nbconvert

I am trying to convert a Colab notebook into a pdf using nbconvert. I am following the steps given in the response to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504490/10138071

Using the `!jupyter nbconvert` command I was able to write the file out to a pdf and save it to my drive. However, I would like to hide the code from the pdf output. The command-line parameter for hiding python code using nbconvert is `--no-input`. However, when I add in this line I get the following error:

```
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.420 ...s/<filename>_16_0.png}
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

The `--no-input` command seems to cause the script to not write anything to output. This is an error that I only find when running `nbconvert` within a Google Colab notebook, the pdf is renderred fine (without code showing) when I try to run `nbconvert` in my local computer's terminal.