# How to upload online pdf files in my google drive using colab

Tags: file-upload, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to upload pdf files in my google drive using colab but i was unable to upload kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Why do need to upload them via colab? Just upload them too google drive and check whether you can access them in colab.
If you want to convert notebooks into pdf check the article [convert google colab to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748816/convert-google-colab-notebook-to-pdf-html)